# Android Studio change checkbox result when changing language in app

Tags: checkbox

I made an app where a user can check a box(checkbox).
Also the app can be translated in 2 languages by code.
How can I also make the result of the checkbox(true/false) to be translated when you change the language of the app?

I have not found something similar anywhere online.